# Can zen coding go back to the previous level?

Tags: html, web, emmet

zen coding is a nice tool.
But can zen coding go back to the previous level?
Look at this example:

```
<p>
    <span class="footnote1"></span>
<p>
<p>
    <span class="footnote2"></span>
<p>
<p>
    <span class="footnote3"></span>
<p>
```

First, i write `p>span.footnote$` so i go into the level of `<span>`.
Is there any abbreviations provided in zen coding can go back the previous level `<p>`.

Comment: Zen coding isn't an app. Are you in Sublime Text? Dreamweaver? The Chrome Extension? Notepad++? Vim? All these will have ways to do this. The quickest cross platform way is to press up 3-4 times. (`4k` in vim by the way).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The upcoming version of Zen Coding, which will be renamed to Emmet, provides `^` operator to climb up one level up the tree: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#misc

Note that in current version of Zen Coding you can use *grouping* to create complex structures:

`(p>span.footnote$)+(.footer>p{This is my copyright})`

You can get the latest beta plugin for Notepad++ here: https://github.com/sergeche/zen-coding/downloads

Comment: Thank you Sergey :)
You made a fantastic tool !
I will wait for your new release with patient :)

Comment: I have been waiting a long time for this feature: +2!